# Call to theme_captcha function in captcha module

Tags: captcha

I put a display at the top of the theme_captcha function in the captcha module for a particular form and it is getting into the function but where does this function get called from ??

Comment: Grep the modules folder for `'#theme' => 'captcha'` or `theme('captcha'`, that should find it

Comment: Thanks Clive.  I wasn't able to locate it yet but the bigger issue for me is that my client gave me some html code for a form to replace an existing webform because of some email problems.  I tried including it in the webform itself but couldn't get it to work so I ended up adding it to the node.tpl.php using php print statements.  Now they want to activate the captcha in it and I can't figure out how to trigger it.  Hope that makes sense.  Anyone have any thoughts on this ??

Comment: You can't expect to use functionality provided by a Drupal inside a form that doesn't use the Drupal API unfortunately. I don't know the situation of course, but with the utmost respect to all involved, _you_ need to be telling your client what HTML you're going to use, not the other way round. If I were you I'd concentrate on solving the original issue using the Drupal form API, then you can use Captcha or any other number of bot-throttling modules with a few clicks of the mouse. This is a good place to get help with such things, just get the relevant parts of code into a question

Comment: @Clive - Fair enough.  I will create a new separate question.